# How to develop formula based on contents of two cells

Tags: excel-formula

I'm setting up an excel document and can't figure out the formula to this problem.

I want the formula to read:

1. If cell x is equal to `Yes`

   - if cell y is less then `1` it equals `0`
   - if cell y is `1` or `2` then equals `1`
   - if cell y is `3` or more then equals cell y multiplied by `2`
2. if cell x was equal to `No`

   - if cell y is less than `5` then it equals `0`
   - if cell y is more than `5` and less than `26` then equal that number
   - if more then `25` then equal `26`

I have tried using different IF and IFS statements but cannot find a formula that works.

Answer (score 0):

Standard IF with two CHOOSE(MATCH())

```
=IF(A1="Yes",CHOOSE(MATCH(B1,{-1E+99,1,3}),0,1,B1*2),IF(A1="No",CHOOSE(MATCH(B1,{-1E+99,5,26}),0,B1,26),0))
```

[image]

---

With IFS:

```
=IF(A1="Yes",IFS(B1<1,0,B1<3,1,TRUE,B1*2),IF(A1="No",IFS(B1<5,0,B1<26,B1,TRUE,26),0))
```

Nested IFS:

```
=IFS(A1="Yes",IFS(B1<1,0,B1<3,1,TRUE,B1*2),A1="No",IFS(B1<5,0,B1<26,B1,TRUE,26),TRUE,0)
```

Comment: I should have added that in the column with Yes and No, there are other words, which would result in a 0 for the final formula. How do I add that to the IFS statement?

Comment: @ChloeDuncan See Edit

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach with two small tables and vlookup.

May be easier to edit and control, up to you.

[image]